# How to get .NET .dll version from ASP

Tags: .net, dll, com, asp-classic

I have an **classic** ASP site and a .NET .dll file.
How to get .dll version from **classic** ASP code?

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ClassInThatAssembly))
    .GetName().Version.ToString();
```